# Generating arbitrary `JointList` with concrete types

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am writing tests for one of the exercises of [this course homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures/07-folds-monoids.html).

In this homework the following data type is defined:

```
data JoinList m a = Empty
              | Single m a
              | Append m (JoinList m a) (JoinList m a)
              deriving (Eq, Show)
```

To carry out the tests, I would like to generate random `JointList` elements using `QuickCheck`, in such a way that `m` is a `Monoid` that carries information about the number of elements in the list. This is, I would like to define `arbitrary` as follows:

```
instance (Sized m0, Monoid m0, Arbitrary a0) => 
    (Arbitrary (JoinList m0 a0)) where
  arbitrary = oneof [ return Empty
                    , liftM (Single (Size 1)) arbitrary
                    , liftM2 (doAppend) arbitrary arbitrary
                    ]
              where doAppend jxs jys = Append (tag jxs <> tag jys) jxs jys
```

where `<>` is defined as the sum of the sizes of the two operands, and the `Sized` class is defined as follows:

```
newtype Size = Size Int
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)

class Sized a where
  size :: a -> Size
```

However, this results in the following compiler error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘m0’ with actual type ‘Size’
  ‘m0’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the instance declaration at test/Spec.hs:35:10
Relevant bindings include
  arbitrary :: Gen (JoinList m0 a0) (bound at test/Spec.hs:36:3)
In the first argument of ‘Single’, namely ‘(Size 1)’
In the first argument of ‘liftM’, namely ‘(Single (Size 1))’
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that rather than supporting producing random lists annotated by user-chosen instances of `Sized`, you really intended just to support producing random lists annotated by the specific type `Size`. You can modify your `Arbitrary` instance declaration this way to do that:

```
instance (m ~ Size, Arbitrary a) => Arbitrary (JoinList m a) where
    -- as before
```

You will want to declare the obvious `Monoid` instance for `Size`:

```
instance Monoid Size where
    mempty  = 0
    mappend = (+)
```

You can skip declaring the `Sized` class entirely.

Alternately, if you really did intend to produce random lists annotated by user-chosen instances, then you need the `Sized` class to provide a way to *produce* annotations, rather than consuming them as the class currently provides. Thus, for example:

```
class Sized a where size :: Int -> a
instance Sized Size where size = Size
```

Then the `Arbitrary` instance declaration would remain the same, but would replace `Size` with `size` in the production for `Single`.

Comment: I didn't know about [type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families)!

You are right in that I only want specific instances of Sized, so the first approach does the trick.

Thank you.